# Javascript parentheses around statements (not IIFE)

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

Recently I've learned a new trick with JavaScript which I do not fully understand.

I know that you need to put ( ) around objects when using fat arrrow / lambda expressions like so:

example:

```
fetch(..).then((response) => ({ data: response } ))
```

But how come this also works:

```
const text = (await fetch(...).then(response => response.text()))
```

because if you would do

```
const text = await fetch(...)...
```

you obviously get [object Promise].

Would love to know why this works. I have been trying to Google this, but only stumble upon IIFE, but that is like (....)(); with the extra () at the end.

Comment: The parentheses don't do *anything* there, it's the await. And I'd generally recommend not mixing async/await with .then/.catch.

Comment: Parens are optional for fat arrow notation if you have exactly one parameter. `a => body` and `(a) => body` are equivalent.

Comment: @RaymondChen He's talking about the parens around the object, which are required to prevent it from being treated as a function body.

Comment: `a => { foo: bar}` is different from `a => ({foo: bar})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses in:

```
const text = (await fetch(...).then(response => response.text()));
```

Are called the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) and are normally used to change the [default precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The documentation uses a good example:

> ```
> var a = 1;
> var b = 2;
> var c = 3;
>
> // default precedence
> a + b * c     // 7
> // evaluated by default like this
> a + (b * c)   // 7
>
> // now overriding precedence
> // addition before multiplication
> (a + b) * c   // 9
>
> // which is equivalent to
> a * c + b * c // 9
> ```

However you could just as easily use them when they are not needed.

```
var a = 1;
var a = (1);
var a = ((1));
```

All the lines above do exactly the same. Coming back to your code the following lines are equivalent:

```
var text = await fetch(...).then(response => response.text());
var text = (await fetch(...).then(response => response.text()));
```

They do make a difference in the following context:

```
var text = await promise.toUpperCase();
var text = (await promise).toUpperCase();
```

The first line will call `toUpperCase` upon `promise`, then `await` the result of `toUpperCase`. Since a promise does not have the method `toUpperCase` it will crash.

The second line will first `await` the `promise` result, then call `toUpperCase` on the resulting value. Which works perfectly fine (assuming the promise resolves into a string).

Answer (score 1):

`(response) => ({data: response})` will return an object with the property `data` set to the response object. `response => response.text()` will return a promise. Like commented, when a single paramenter is used in an arrow function, the paranthesis are optional.